# Passing data to vue.js method

Tags: vue.js

I have a variable with color. I want to change the color of the text. How can I set this variable to v-bind: style event?

```
  <div class="drop" :style="'color:{{item.color}};'">
     some text
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of `style` binding:

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data: () => ({ item: { color:'red' } })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="drop" :style="{ color: item.color }">
    some text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Max you're welcome, please mark the answer as the solution to close the question

Answer (score 1):

As described in the Vue documentation [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1), you can use the following object syntax to bind styles:

```
<div class="drop" :style="{ color: item.color }">
     some text
</div>
```